# Sum with nulls "not working" in SQL Server / Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, null, average

I'm trying to average a set of columns and exclude rows with zero from the denominator by using a case statement within an AVG() function. I read that avg() excludes NULL results so am using the case statement to replace 0's with NULL's. However that's not what I find in practice - see code below. Can someone explain why this happens?  If you can suggest a code tweak to achieve what I'm after that would also be fab. Thanks.

```
with a as
(
select 0 t1, 3 t2 
)
, b as
(
select 6 t1, 0 t2
)
, c as -- building a small table containing test data.
(
select * from a
union all
select * from b
)
select sum(case when t2 = 0 then null else t2 end + case when t1 = 0 then null else t1 end) r1 
  , avg(case when t2 = 0 then null else t2 end + case when t1 = 0 then null else t1 end) r2
  , avg(t1) r3
from c
```

What subquery c contains:

| t1 | t2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 |

The actual result of my query:

| r1 | r2 | r3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 3 |

Column `r2` is what I would like the result of my query to be: `avg(3 + null, null + 6) = avg(3, 6) = 4.5`:

| r1 | r2 | r3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 4.5 | 3 |

Comment: 3 + null = null

Comment: `select sum(t2 + t1) r1, avg(t2 + t1) r2, avg(t1) r3 from c` and forget about your case, but to get 4.5 you will need to make either t2 or t1 (or both) decimal

Comment: Or to put it another way, 3 beans plus some beans = some beans

Comment: @Stu I think it is more clear to say that 3 beans + an unknown number of beans = an unknown number of beans

Comment: If `a = 0, 0` and `b = 6, 0` what should the results be?  If `a = 1, 2` and `b = 6, 0` what should the results be?  Can any of the values ever be `NULL`?  At present your objective is ambiguous/unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the 0 values to `null`, you can filter them out somewhere in between:

```sql
with a as
(
select cast(0 as float) t1, cast(3 as float) t2 
)
, b as
(
select cast(6 as float) t1, cast(0 as float) t2
)
, c as -- building a small table containing test data.
(
select * from a where t1 > 0 or t2 > 0
union all
select * from b where t1 > 0 or t2 > 0
)
select sum(t2+t1) r1 
  , avg(t2+t1) r2
  , avg(t1) r3
from c;
```

**Output:**

```
| r1 | r2 | r3 |
|----+----+----|
| 9  | 4.5| 3  |
```

*See how I convert numbers to `float` type, in order to capture the floating point on `r2`.

Comment: won't r2 = 4 in stead of 4.5 ?

Comment: Nope, it will output the average between 6 and 3, which is 4.5. Why would it be 4?

Comment: Because you are using all int for the calculation, and when I run it I get 4 in stead of 4.5

Comment: See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6966509fac5f54b5ec7012a857fe86b6)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, was not using a sql-server rdbms on my end, and was automatically converting to float. Have updated the answer!

Comment: This is better, shorter would be `select 0.0 as t1`

Comment: Yep, that would be shorter! But not sure if OP is able to change the data points, therefore a recasting might be easier :)

Comment: Yes, you have a point there